# JFrame drag listener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I am looking for some sort of WindowMotionListener or something of that sort, so when I drag a window by the title bar (or otherwise) I can get location information the same way I would with a MouseMotionListener. I'm trying to make a Swing component that works sort of like MFC does, where you can drag a window into a location and have it snap into it (example: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vKRR.jpg**).

So far, I've gotten the snapping down and the dragging when the user drags the frame by it's contents, but not by title bar which would be much easier for the end user. Is there any way to do get a sort of window drag event? Would I have to make my own windows decorations and add a "drag" even to them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: *but not by title bar*  - the frame and its title bar is not a Swing component. It is a widget of the OS so you can't control its dragging behaviour. *Would I have to make my own windows decorations and add a "drag" even to them?* - yes. Maybe the [Component Mover](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) can help out. It allows you to drag the frame by dragging a component on the frame.

Comment: Darn, well thank you for the info. I have already made my components move the frame, but I may make my own style of frame to accomplish what I intend to then.

Comment: What do you mean *but not by title bar*? Do you for example mean that you want to drag the window around? And what about *snapping*? You mean for example that you want the dragged window to snap to a different window? Also, can you post how did you *got the snapping down and the dragging* so that we can work from there on? Can you, if applicable, give an image of the expected behaviour and the actual (undesired) behaviour?

Comment: I want to get events when the window is moved. Also, the snapping has nothing to do with the question, my main issue is that there is no way to determine if a user is dragging a jframe around

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear, I tried clarifying it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get events when the window is moved. ... my main issue is that there is no way to determine if a user is dragging a jframe around

Well, what about a `ComponentListener` on the `JFrame`?...

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drag frame");
        
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(final ComponentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("New frame location: " + frame.getLocation());
            }

            @Override
            public void componentResized(final ComponentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("New frame size: " + frame.getSize());
            }
        });
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Drag the title bar and see the logs..."));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: My god! I've been writing Java programs for years, I cannot believe I never thought something so standard would work! Thank you very much!!!