# Titlebar of JFrame not recognizing mouse events

Tags: java, swing

I have a user that uses 3 monitors of different sizes, I want to use a mouse dragged event listener to detect when the user drags the window to another screen and resize it based on that screens size. When I add a mouse event listener to the jframe doesn't detect events on the title bar. Is there a way to detect titlebar events? or a better approach to this problem?

I tried also tried using AWTEventListener but had the same problem where it won't detect events in the titlebar.

Test Code showing issue:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame
{
   JPanel pnl;
   JLabel lbl;
   
   public FrameTest()
   {
      setSize(1100,800); 
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setTitle("Frame Test");
            
      pnl = new JPanel();
      lbl = new JLabel("This is my Frame");
      
      add(pnl);
      pnl.add(lbl);
      
      setVisible(true);
      FrameTest.this.addMouseListener(new MouseMotionEvents());  
      FrameTest.this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionEvents());


   }
   
   public class MouseMotionEvents implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener 
   {
     
     public MouseMotionEvents() 
     {
       addMouseListener(this);
       addMouseMotionListener(this); 
     }
   
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
     {     
     }

     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) 
     {
     }

     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) 
     {
     }

     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) 
     {
     }

     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) 
     {
      
     }

     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) 
     {
      System.out.println("Mouse Dragged Event Triggered");
     }

     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) 
     {
     }
   }
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) 
   {
      new FrameTest();
   }
}
```

Comment: @Jesse No, the program is being used on macOS Big Sur 11.6

Comment: *When I add a mouse event listener to the jframe doesn't detect events on the title bar* - correct, the title bar is a component of the underlying OS and Swing doesn't have access to those events. *a better approach to this problem?* - maybe use a `ComponentListener` and handle the `componentMoved` event. Or the other approach is to use jni/jna to access the events. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Any `MouseListener` is not intended for this. You could use a `ComponentListener` to determine if a `Frame` has been moved by the user. [jframe-drag-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66825216/jframe-drag-listener)

Comment: @camickr Thank you, this was the solution. ComponentListener worked well